# WP Query. Ordering posts by another post types meta

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query, order

I have a custom post type called BID which contains a users bid (similar to freelancer.com, upwork, etc) However I need the BID results on the page to be ordered by meta stored in a users profile, which is a custom post type PROFILE.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is my current Query

```
new WP_Query( array(    'post_type' => BID,

                        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),

                        'posts_per_page' => 20,

                        'post_status' => array('publish','complete', 'accept', 'unaccept')

                            )

               );
```

Comment: Sorry, ignore my answer. (If you've seen it..) It is possible to sort the posts by custom field from another post type, which you can do so via hooks such as `posts_orderby`. But it's probably not going to be a simple task, and you need to write custom SQL query/queries.

Comment: While this is possible through using some Wordpress Filters and some serious f*ckery with the "normal" SQL Queries the WP_Query would normally do, there is not enough info. How exactly are the PROFILE and BID Post Types connected?

Comment: Profile and BID types are connected by the user that created the post. Both are owner by the same user.

Comment: @MiguelDey so the post *author* is the same user?

Comment: @SallyCJ the BID author and the Profile author are the same users yes.
The ID of the users profile page is stored in their usermeta.

Comment: So there are two custom fields - one on the Profile post edit page (`wp-admin/post.php`) and the other on the user edit page such as `wp-admin/user-edit.php`? What are the field names (meta keys)? Maybe you can show the code that creates those fields?

Comment: One is the "profile" post type and the other is the "Bid" post type... In order to know the profile page for each user, the id for is stored in the usermeta.

What I'm trying to accomplish is sorting "bids" post type by ranking meta in the "profile" post type